Find out if notification action needs a switch to the app from adb dump
Is it possible to find out (just from the data accessible by either adb output or by looking at files in android) if the click on a notification action needs a switch to the app?
Example: For a signal message, there can be 2 actions: "Mark as read" and "Answer" where the first does not open the app but the second does.
In order to investigate this, I already found:

adb shell dumpsys notifications which shows me for the signal notification the following two actions:

  [0] "Mark as read" -> PendingIntent{581f34a: PendingIntentRecord{4ad4adb org.thoughtcrime.securesms broadcastIntent (allowlist: f4bd19f:+30s0ms/0/NOTIFICATION_SERVICE/NotificationManagerService)}}
  [1] "Answer" -> PendingIntent{5b152bb: PendingIntentRecord{af9c978 org.thoughtcrime.securesms broadcastIntent (allowlist: f4bd19f:+30s0ms/0/NOTIFICATION_SERVICE/NotificationManagerService)}}


adb shell dumpsys activity intents in which I can search for the id of the PendingIntentRecords and find the following two counterparts for our actions (I added newlines for better readability):

    #17: PendingIntentRecord{4ad4adb
      org.thoughtcrime.securesms broadcastIntent (allowlist: f4bd19f:+30s0ms/0/NOTIFICATION_SERVICE/NotificationManagerService)}
      uid=10066 packageName=org.thoughtcrime.securesms featureId=null type=broadcastIntent flags=0x2000000
      requestCode=444 requestResolvedType=null
      requestIntent=act=org.thoughtcrime.securesms.notifications.CLEAR
      dat=custom://1726327070791 cmp=org.thoughtcrime.securesms/.notifications.MarkReadReceiver (has extras)
      allowlistDuration=f4bd19f:+30s0ms/0/NOTIFICATION_SERVICE/NotificationManagerService

    #10: PendingIntentRecord{af9c978
      org.thoughtcrime.securesms broadcastIntent (allowlist: f4bd19f:+30s0ms/0/NOTIFICATION_SERVICE/NotificationManagerService)}
      uid=10066 packageName=org.thoughtcrime.securesms featureId=null type=broadcastIntent flags=0x2000000
      requestCode=445 requestResolvedType=null
      requestIntent=act=org.thoughtcrime.securesms.notifications.WEAR_REPLY
      dat=custom://1726327070801 cmp=org.thoughtcrime.securesms/.notifications.RemoteReplyReceiver (has extras)
      allowlistDuration=f4bd19f:+30s0ms/0/NOTIFICATION_SERVICE/NotificationManagerService


Nothing from these two sources seems to tell me if clicking on the action will lead android to switch to the app or not. Did I miss something or can I find the information elsewhere?
